# Do I need TFS installed on the machine that will use some dlls to communicate remotely to it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5, com+

I guess not, but here's the catch:

I've made a COM+ Object to be used from a machine where neither VisualStudio or TFS are installed. And this COM+ Object has referenced TFS dlls to make a login on a remote TFS server and create Work Items.

And I have another additional issue. I used VS2012 and TFS2010, so the dlls referenced say 11.0.0.0 when I think they should say 10.0.0.0 or somethin of that style.

I checked on this [TFS 2010 build failing because it can't load Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Plugins.CodeCoverage version 11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14349528/684646)
...but I can't see if it's useful for me, and if it is, how.

This is the exact error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

And maybe, (as I tried to say in the title), it requires to have something installed on the machine... But this machine is a server, and it bothers me a bit to install new stuff on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The 11.0 DLLs are fine - it means you're using the 2012 client DLLs, but they work fine against a 2010 TFS server.

If VS is not installed on the machine where your app is running, you will need to deploy them with your app.  See http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx to know what DLLs are required and where to get them.

Comment: I'm kind of confused... I've been looking into it... Does this mean I need to install the sdk on the server?

Comment: that's one solution, but I don't think it's required.  Just take the required DLLs and copy them to the server in the same directory as your app.

Comment: I've done that already, but it's like they aren't there, what am I missing?. Maybe I can make some punctual reference on the registry or something? I don't know... But I certainly do want to avoid the SDK installing (Unless there's no other way).

Comment: If you have all the required DLLs in the same folder as the application that's trying to use them, and it's still failing with the same error, then maybe it's something that has to do with COM+ - consider retagging the question to get some attention from people that know about COM+